# Symfony Collection constraint of a numeric field

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, constraints

To make sure my array contains keys ['extension_attributes']['shipping_assignments'][0]['shipping']
I want to use the following Collection constraint validation

```
Collection:
    allowExtraFields: true
    fields:
        extension_attributes:
            -   Collection:
                    allowExtraFields: true
                    fields:
                        shipping_assignments:
                            -   Collection:
                                    allowExtraFields: true
                                    fields:
                                        0:
                                            -   Collection:
                                                    allowExtraFields: true
                                                    fields:
                                                        shipping: ~
```

But i have on error on validation because i use the numeric key 0

> Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Loader\AbstractLoader::newConstraint(): Argument #1 ($name) must be of type string, int given, called in /var/www/ht
> ml/vendor/cleverage/process-bundle/Validator/ConstraintLoader.php on line 44

fields option in Collection constraint cannot accept numeric key

Answer (score 0):

Update

Error is due to the constraint loader
if i use php and not yaml for constraint definition it works

Work

```
$constraint = new Assert\Collection(
    [
        'fields' => [
            0 => [new Assert\NotBlank()]
        ]
    ]
);
```

Not work

```
Collection:
    fields:
        0:  [NotBlank]
```